# Forcing the orientation of a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiinterfaceorientation

Much has been written on this topic and I am wondering, why I only find "kind of hacks" to achieve it.

Don't get me wrong, I have a solution to the problem for iOS 6 and 7 and another solution for iOS 8.

It appears to be such a basic requirement, when working with orientations, that I can not believe, that there is no "recommended way".

Here's the (common?) scenario:
Your iPhone app wants to run almost always in Portrait mode. Only a few ViewControllers want to support landscape, like for example an Image viewer or a video viewer.

So you need to allow all orientations in the project settings and decide on view controller base, which orientations to support on a per View Controller base.

With a category on UINavigationController and UITabBarController, you rather simply get the required events routed to your view controllers in order to let them decide, which orientation they "prefer".

All this works well unless you currently ARE in a certain orientation, which is not supported in the view controller you are navigating to, for example as result of a pop or push navigation.

Here we now need to "force" the orientation. And somehow this has always required kind of a hack. Before I put up an empty view controller modally and dismissed it right away, which triggered the orientation change. Ugly... Now in iOS 8 it is less ugly, but still somewhat hardcoded and with a taste of using undocumented methods: `UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(NSNumber(integer: UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue), forKey: "orientation")`

Now I am wondering, this must be such a common thing. Why isn't there a solution, which feels like the "Apple provided way"??

Having some kind of "viewer" for images and videos, which support portrait and landscape, where anything else does only support Portrait, seems to be such a common setup, that everybody, Apple engineers included, must have the same problem, when hitting the "back" button in the image viewer while in landscape mode and then returning to the previous view, which must be forced to "Portrait" on viewDidAppear, so the user is "forced" to rotate the device back to Portrait.

Am I overlooking something obvious??
I can't achieve a proper solution without these "hacks" to force the orientation on the device.

Comment: I agree with you, this can be very frustrating. However I simplify such works by using this library here https://github.com/hfossli/AGWindowView

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting, but the question was rather, why is there no "official way" to such a common problem, or is it not a problem at all to other developers and therefore doesn't need to be solved in the cocoa framework.

Comment: The becomes an issue only when one needs diverse behaviors with viewcontrollers contained in navigation controller stack. Apple might ask why one should do that - There are always other options like presentViewController:animated: for the "viewer" example that you mentioned above.

Comment: You are absolutely right and that serves me as a good answer. Add it as an answer and I will accept it. It makes sense and I need to reconsider. whether it is a better idea to not have differing orientation requirements for view controllers within the same navigation controller stack. Thanks, that makes perfectly sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The becomes an issue only when one needs diverse behaviours with viewcontrollers contained in navigation controller stack. Apple might ask why one should do that - There are always other options like `presentViewController:animated:` for the "viewer" example that you mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

iOS 7 and above

```
 NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```